# How to use django-phonenumber_field in forms.py?

Tags: django

I was trying to take phone number from user as part of his profile updating. I recently found out from `stackoverflow` that there's a library `django-phonenumber_field` with which I can easily take input the phone number. So I used it in the `model.py` like this

`phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)`.

As it is mentioned in the `django-phonenumber_field github repository` [here](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field)

that

> As with CharField's, it is discouraged to use null=True.

So I didn't use that too. Then I tried to use that `phone field` in `forms.py`. Initially I was using this before came to know about `phone field`:

`phone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), required=True)`

When I am changing it to `phone = PhoneNumberField()`

and I'm migrating, it raised `field error`. . I coudln't find any `forms.PhoneNumberField()`. So when I'm keeping the field to be the `Integerfield` and running the server, I tried to get the input from user I get this error:

`NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_profile.phone`

Then I changed `phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)` to `phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True).`  which is discouraged. After that, though I didn't get any error but it doesn't matter what user type in the `phone-field` it always sets `null` in the database. Probably because I used `Integerfield` I kept in the `forms.py` mentioned above. Or I don't know the reason.

How can I add the `PhoneNumberField()` in the `form` or any mechanism so that in the database, user given value will be saved?

**Edit**
As @Sam Bobel told me to post the `models.py` in details, here it is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.dispatch import receiver
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    # url = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    # job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    user_sex = (('MALE', 'Male'), ('FEMALE', 'Female'))
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=6, default='Male', choices=user_sex)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    zip = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account_type = models.IntegerField(default=-1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Now if I run migrations, I get

```
You are trying to change the nullable field 'phone' on profile to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
 3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

`**forms.py`**:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    address = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 4}),
        max_length=300,
        required=True)
    city = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        max_length=30,
        required=True)
    state = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        max_length=30,
        required=True)
    country = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        max_length=30,
        required=True)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        required=True)
    zip = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['address', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'phone', 'zip']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I am using phonenumber field in my project and till now it was working without any problems. Also I didn't have any troubles with migrations.

Inside model:

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

phonenumber = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
```

Inside form:

```
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField

class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    phonenumber = PhoneNumberField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Phone')}), 

                       label=_("Phone number"), required=False)
```

Comment: I got this error:

`super(PhoneNumberField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'
`

Comment: I hope you import from FORMFIELDS (from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField) and not from MODELFIELDS like from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Should have watched carefully. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Yes, authors have made the same names both for form field and model so it is easy to mistype!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to import PhoneNumberField from the wrong place. If I'm understanding correctly, `forms.PhoneNumberField` doesn't exist.

First, make sure that `phonenumber_field` is in your installed apps (The library's README shows how to do this.

Second, make sure you're importing it correctly. `from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField` should be at the top of your models.py

Third, in your model, say `field_name = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)

Then you should be able to do your migrations.

If this is way off base, would you post your model-code more in full?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find anything like `forms.PhoneNumberField` too.
I have `phonenumber_field` in my installed apps. I had `from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField` in `models.py` though not in the top. And if I omit `null=True` in the `PhoneNumberField()` it asks me to put some default values first.

Comment: I've posted the `models.py`

Comment: Would you post your import statement too? And finally, the complete error message you get when migrating?

Comment: I've posted the imports

Comment: I think you're all good, that's not an error. It's saying: this used to be able to be null, and now it can't. What should we do with the old NULL values?

You should type "1" to add a one-off default, and provide the default of an empty string. That will set all the values that used to be NULL to "", which should be fine.

Comment: But isn't there a conflict? As I am using IntegerField in my `forms.py` to get input from user whereas I'm using `PhoneNumberField` in the `models.py`!

Comment: Okay. I did it and now I get error after giving input to the `phone field` and hitting the `submit` button. The error is 

`IntegrityError at /client/contact
NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_profile.phone`

Comment: I'm not perfectly clear on the problem, but my guess is that it has to do with the last line of the django-phonenumber-field readme. It says you need a phone number like "+41524204242"

Comment: last thing we can try: can you post your form code?

Comment: I've posted the `forms.py`. Sorry for being late.

Comment: Look in the repository for django-phonenumber-field -- The FormField is `from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField`.

Comment: It's sort of a weirdly laid out library. But look through those folders on github to find future fields.

Comment: Is there any other way to take Phone Number as input?

Comment: why not just use theirs?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your comment "But look through those folders on github to find future fields. " What should I look for?

Comment: I'm saying that this folder (https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/tree/master/phonenumber_field) has all the code for the project. And you can look at the files to figure out what you should import from where. Can you import the right formField now?

Comment: No I can't import. Couldn't find any form there with which I can use the PhoneNumberField!